# How we can overwrite class name of the object.?

Tags: ruby

How we can overwrite the class name of an object ?

```
Example: 
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> class Man
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> obj = Man.new
=> #<Man:0xb7756464>
irb(main):004:0> puts obj.class
Man
=> nil
```

I want some thing like that

```
puts obj.class 
Van instead of Man
 => nil
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There might be a better way to get where you want to go, setting up an object to lie about its class sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Yup, academic interest aside (it's fun doing such things for person like me, who's just starting with Ruby) this sounds like not all that good idea.

Comment: @mu is too short: "For the LOLs" is reason enough if it's in your own time.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A; end
B = A.clone
o = B.new
p o.class
=> B
```

Answer (score 0):

Remeber, that `class` method does not return a class name (a string), but actually a constant class object. You'd need to create a class `Van` first, then override `obj.class` method, so that it returns `Van` instead of `Man`

```
irb(main):001:0> class Man
irb(main):002:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> class Van
irb(main):004:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> obj = Man.new
=> #<Man:0x25043b8>
irb(main):006:0> def obj.class
irb(main):007:1>   Van
irb(main):008:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> obj.class
=> Van
```

`is_a?` and other methods might need overriding too

```
irb(main):010:0> obj.is_a? Man
=> true
irb(main):011:0> obj.is_a? Van
=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

I know how to overwrite the apparent class name:

```
class Man
  def self.inspect
    "Van"
  end
end

irb(main):007:0* m = Man.new
=> #<Man:0x144ace0>
irb(main):008:0> m.class
=> Van
```

(ActiveRecord does something similar)

But doing a convincing forgery of object inspection is tricky. I don't know how to do the `0xb7756464` bit in `#<Man:0xb7756464>`, so I don't know how to re-implement `Man#inspect`.

Comment: You're looking for `super.sub('Man', 'Van')` (which could also be a band name) in your `inspect`.

Comment: @mu is too short: Yeah, but that's a little hacky.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm your answer doesn't work with `puts`, but if you def `to_s` instead of `inspect` both `puts` and `p` will print `Van`.

Comment: Hacky? Completely unlike lying about what class you're in :)

Comment: @mu is too short: Yes. That's not hacky, that's downright evil! :)